# use jquery in angular js function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to just write jquery inside angularjs function.but don't know why it is not working?

HTML

```
<div>
   <span ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-if="$index <= 3" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon= false" ng-mouseover="image.showDeleteIcon=true" ng-mouseleave="image.showDeleteIcon=false">
   <span ng-if="$index == 3" ng-init="setImgCounter(post.postImages.length,$parent.$index+''+$index)"></span>
   <a id="{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" onclick="SetDataGallery(this.id)" ng-href="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}">
   <img class="img-responsive feed-photo" ng-src="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}" alt="Photo" style="display:inline;">
   <a href="#" class="imgDelete" ng-if="post.timelineStrore.hasControl" ng-show="image.showDeleteIcon" title="Delete Photo" ng-click="DeletePostAttachment(post.timelineStrore.id, image.postAttachmentId,'image')">
   <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
   </a>
   </a>
   </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.setImgCounter = function (counter,id)
{
    $("#" + id + " img:first-child").css("opacity", "0.5");
}
```

but its not working?

I also tried using =>

```
.att('style','opacity:0.5');
```

Comment: Where you are calling `setImgCounter`?

Comment: i recommend you don't use jq in angular code. so try use `$scope.$apply();` after jquery code.

Comment: Please people stop using jQuery AND Angular together. Either you do things the jQuery way, OR the Angular way, not both.

Comment: @JeremyThille is there any way to change css on runtime using angular js?

Comment: Of course there is. Everything you can do with jQuery, you can also do with Angular. But the Angular way :) [Documentation : ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: ok. can you give console.log($("#" + id + " img:first-child")) inside that function and show us the out put.

Comment: nayan : please check my answer below it might help you understanding the angular way of dynamically changing css. hope it helps you.

Comment: @biswajit-rout out is => #33 img:first-child

Comment: you did not see the html element in console. Means after console.log( console.log($("#" + id + " img:first-child")) ) . It will show the html element of id "#33 img:first-child". Just check it.  I think this $("#" + id + " img:first-child")) unable to access the html element. So it cant give the possible output.

Comment: If my previous comment is not clear to you . you can create a sample fiddle and share it . This help us to find the solution faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better not to use jquery with angular**

**Here is an angular way to achieve your requirement**

Since you are trying to make every first child `image` as `opacity 0.5` the loop always makes every images as first child/

So, you can use **`ng-style`** in the image div to apply the `opacity`.

**`ng-style="{'opacity': '0.5'}"`**

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-if="$index <= 3" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon= false" ng-mouseover="image.showDeleteIcon=true" ng-mouseleave="image.showDeleteIcon=false">
        <span ng-if="$index == 3" ng-init="setImgCounter(post.postImages.length,$parent.$index+''+$index)"></span>
        <a id="{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" onclick="SetDataGallery(this.id)" ng-href="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}">
            <img class="img-responsive feed-photo" ng-src="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}" alt="Photo" style="display:inline;" ng-style="{ 'opacity' : ($index == 3) ? '0.5' : '1' }">
            <a href="#" class="imgDelete" ng-if="post.timelineStrore.hasControl" ng-show="image.showDeleteIcon" title="Delete Photo" ng-click="DeletePostAttachment(post.timelineStrore.id, image.postAttachmentId,'image')">
                <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </a>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Since the image is the `first-child` to anchor, it will only apply to `image`..but not `i` tag.

**Note:** If you wanted to apply it only for 3rd index, you can also use condition in `ng-style`. Angular is so flexible.

**`ng-style="{ 'opacity' : ($index == 3) ? '0.5' : '1' }"`**

I think this is your requirement.. pls ask me if any queries.

Comment: cant use because i only need to add opacity when the $index = 3.

Comment: you can use, check this and updated answer , `ng-style="{ 'opacity' : ($index == 3) ? '0.5' : '1' }"`

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-class** for dynamically changing css using angularjs. **This will allow you to dynamically set classes**.

I assume you have your classes defined in a style-sheet that is loaded into memory.

```
.white{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.black{
    color: #000000;
}
```

In your angular controller you can have a variable defined that will hold your class-name. Here I am setting it to apply 'white' by default.

```
$scope.myClass = "white";
```

Then in your markup you simply bind that variable to your element with ng-class.

```
<div ng-class="myClass">....</div>
```

Now, whenever $scope.myclass changes the appropriate class will be added to the div and the old class will be removed. So, in your controller you'll have something that will trigger a change...

```
if( some_condition ){
    $scope.myClass = "black";
} else {
    $scope.myClass = "white";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is possibility with angular then don't use JQuery

Do this instead and make sure `document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + " img:first-child")` this is getting correct element

```
$scope.setImgCounter = function (counter,id)
{
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + " img:first-child")).css("opacity", "0.5");
}
```

Comment: That is why I said **"make sure document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + " img:first-child") is getting correct element"**. Where you are calling `setImgCounter `?

Comment: after inspaction `  <a id="33" onclick="SetDataGallery(this.id)" ng-href="../upload/post-photos/16b179d6-6644-484c-b6b1-7e896a68242c.jpeg" href="../upload/post-photos/16b179d6-6644-484c-b6b1-7e896a68242c.jpeg">
                                        <img class="img-responsive feed-photo" ng-src="../upload/post-photos/16b179d6-6644-484c-b6b1-7e896a68242c.jpeg" alt="Photo" style="display:inline;" src="../upload/post-photos/16b179d6-6644-484c-b6b1-7e896a68242c.jpeg">
                                        </a> `

Comment: I didn't get you. You mean that is the element you are getting in the console?

Comment: copied from inspaction